# 'str' object has no attribute 'text'. Cant seem to be able to fix it

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

Can someone please help me with this error, ive looked at other ones that had the same error but cant seem to apply it to my code, i dont know if that is because im just bad at coding or that it is because it cant be applied to my code, i would prefer people to send the updated code then that they send me what to do in words cause i normally dont understand it

This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def ipcheck(ctx, IP):
    await ctx.send(get('https://ipapi.co/' + (IP) + '/json/').text)
```

This is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command ipcheck:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\TEST.py", line 51, in ipcheck
    await ctx.send(get('https://ipapi.co/' + (IP) + '/json/').text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `get('https://ipapi.co/' + (IP) + '/json/')` already returns a string, there's no need for you to use the `text` attribute

```py
@client.command()
async def ipcheck(ctx, IP):
    await ctx.send(get('https://ipapi.co/' + (IP) + '/json/'))
```

Comment: I just tried but when i do it the bot only sends: "h" in the chat back, i dont know why this is cause i have tried it with normal python command line and then it works so its not the API. Thanks for the fast responds. I would like to get another reaction back if you know how to fix this. It doesnt show any errors BTW

Comment: Have you tried printing what `get('https://ipapi.co/' + (IP) + '/json/')` returns? Maybe it just returns the single “h”

Comment: Thats what i have done, but it works with print, just doesnt work with the discord bot. If you are down we could maybe try to figure it out in discord call cause i have no idea how to fix

Comment: Yeah sure, feel free to add me: `kwieeciol#6035`

Comment: I just added you, call me whenever. Sorry for late responses every time.

Comment: My discord name is TTSDEK BTW, you added me allready